# Gradle Liquibase change log file could not be found

Tags: gradle, liquibase, build.gradle

Using gradle-liquibase plugin in our project with all dependencies resolved.

I have the following liquibase task as suggested by Gradle liquibase plugin:

```
liquibase {
   activities {
   main {      
      changeLogFile 'src/main/resources/db/dbchangelog-master.xml'
      url 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test'
      username 'XXX'
      password 'XXX'
     } 
  }
 runList = 'main'
}
```

But encountered  problems with the changeLogFile not being identified by liquibase though the logfile is in project classpath directory (src/main/resources/)

Error:

```
Caused by: liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException:
src/main/resources/dbchangelog/db.changelog-master.xml does not exist
```

Any help with regards to how should I resolve this classpath related issue?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just add a classpath parameter where your src directory is

```
liquibase {
   activities {
   main {      
      changeLogFile 'src/main/resources/db/dbchangelog-master.xml'
      url 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test'
      username 'XXX'
      password 'XXX'
      classpath "$rootDir"
     } 
  }
 runList = 'main'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with gradle liquibase plugin version 1.0.0 and found workaround... On your example it would be like:

```
liquibase {
   activities {
   main {      
      changeLogFile "${this.rootDir}/src/main/resources/db/dbchangelog-master.xml"
      url 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test'
      username 'XXX'
      password 'XXX'
     } 
  }
 runList = 'main'
}
```

When you run gradle task from eclipse - it really try to find changelog file in root of eclipse itself...

Comment: Your workaround is good if there is only one liquibase file. But I have a master.xml file with multiple include files: `<include file="src/main/resources/db/dbchangelog-1.0.xml" />` This still gives me the same `Error thrown as a SAXException: src/main/resources/db/dbchangelog-1.0.xml does not exist
`

Comment: @PondicherryFellow 
Hm... it should work...
Do you have in your master xml includes with **relativeToChangelogFile="true"** attribute?
Like:   
 `<include file="common/triggers-changelog.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Is the current directory actually in your classpath? Normally your classpath is configured to include the "target" output directories and possibly "src/main/resources" as another classpath root.

Does it work if you use `changeLogFile 'db/dbchangelog-master.xml'` ?

Comment: I was running the `gradle update` command from eclipse. However my project was in a different directory(c:/myproject) to eclipse workspace(c:/workspace).  `gradle update` works fine when used in a command line outside eclipse from the project directory.

Comment: There is a difference in how Liquibase sets up classpaths depending on how you run Liquibase. Command line by default uses the current directory as a classpath along with whatever else you list with the --classpath parameter. Gradle probably just uses "src/main/resources" as a classpath and does not include the project directory. What you should do is use "db/dbchangelog-master.xml" as the changeLogFile in gradle and when you run from the command line include the --classpath=src/main/rsources paramter

Comment: But that doesnt work from eclipse.... `Caused by: liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: db/changelog-master.xml does not exist`

Comment: You may need to use an absolute path for your classpath attribute like --classpath=c:\myproject\src\main\resources